# Dynamics Great Plains Web Services: Is there a way to retrieve a user's company permissions?

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-gp

Basically is there a call I can make through the GP web services to retrieve what companies a user has access to within Great Plains?

Comment: I'm thinking I might be able to simply make the GetCompanyList() web method call for each user I'm checking privileges for.
And in this call, set the WorkOnBehalfOf property of the Context that I"m passing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe I'm able to simply cycle through my list of users and make the GetCompanyList call for each user using the WorkOnBehalfOf property of the Context.
A bit tedious and potentially a lot of heavy web service calls but I don't believe GP exposes any other way to do this.